# Why do I have to change integers to strings in order to iterate them in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

First of all, I have only recently started to learn Python on codeacademy.com and this is probably a very basic question, so thank you for the help and please forgive my lack of knowledge.

The function below takes positive integers as input and returns the sum of all that numbers' digits. What I don't understand, is why I have to change the type of the input into str first, and then back into integer, in order to add the numbers' digits to each other. Could someone help me out with an explanation please? The code works fine for the exercise, but I feel I am missing the big picture here.

```
def digit_sum(n):
    num = 0

    for i in str(n):
        num += int(i)    
    return num
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integers are not sequences of digits. They are just (whole) numbers, so they can't be iterated over.

By turning the integer into a string, you created a sequence of digits (characters), and a string *can* be iterated over. It is no longer a number, it is now *text*.

See it as a representation; you could also have turned the same number into *hexadecimal text*, or octal text, or binary text. It would still be the same *numerical value*, just written down differently in text.

Iteration over a string works, and gives you *single characters*, which for a number means that each character is also a digit. The code takes that character and turns it back into a number with `int(i)`.

You don't have to use that trick. You could also use maths:

```
def digit_sum(n):  
    total = 0  
    while n:
        n, digit = divmod(n, 10)
        num += digit
    return num
```

This uses a `while` loop, and repeatedly divides the input number by ten (keeping the remainder) until `0` is reached. The remainders are summed, giving you the digit sum. So `1234` is turned into `123` and `4`, then `12` and `3`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the number 12345
So I would need 1,2,3,4,5 from the given number and then sum it up.

So how to get individuals number. One mathematical way was how @Martijn Pieters showed.

Another is to convert it into a string , and make it iterable.

This is one of the many ways to do it.

```
>>> sum(map(int, list(str(12345))))
15
```

The list() function break a string into individual letters. SO I needed a string. Once I have all numbers as individual letters, I can convert them into integers and add them up .